# ngx-translate don't find the url

Tags: asp.net, angular, ngx-translate

i want to translate my static text in my app. the output after running the app is in my example TEST. like the name of my variable. I think, the problem is the url. Only full url like this example works, and i dont know why.

I used ngx-translate in my Angular App on asp.core 2.

I put my the createTranslateLoader function in my app.module.shared.ts. It is loaded by app.module.browser.ts and app.module.server.ts.

```
imports: [
        ...,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),...]
```

and

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    console.log(http);
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'http://localhost:56601/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

My default Language is german 'de'. I put my de.json in wwwroot/i18n/de.json.

At last step i modify my app.component.ts

```
   export class AppComponent {
        constructor(private translate: TranslateService
) {
            translate.addLangs(['en', 'de']);
            translate.setDefaultLang('de');
            translate.use('de');
            //let browserlang = translate.getBrowserLang();
            //translate.use(browserlang.match(/en|de/) ? browserlang : 'de');
        }

}
```

and my app.component.html

```
<p style="color:wheat">{{ 'TEST' | translate }}</p>
```

My de.json looks like

```
{
  "TEST": "Deutscher Test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving i18n folder to assets might resolve your problem. 
And then also modifiying createTranslateLoader:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Comment: I tried it out. Now i get a exception:
URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute. URL: ./assets/i18n/de.json. The fullpath of the  is wwwroot/assets/i18n/de.json

Comment: Try to refactor and use HttpClient instead of Http like so: 

`HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient)`  

and then also in your loader: `{..., deps: [HttpClient] }`  
provided with the follow import statements in app.module:  
`import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 0):

Following is working fine for me with ASPNET.Core and ngx-translate

```
export function translateLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './i18n/', '.json');
}
```

My resource files are inside the wwwroot/i18n/ folder same as yours.

Comment: If this does not works can you see what is the requested resource url in network tab?